# Moving the content of a DIV to another DIV with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/scripts/demo/jquery02.html

According to [this link](http://www.elated.com/articles/jquery-removing-replacing-moving-elements/) elements can be moved around by doing $('#container1').append($('#container2')).  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working for me.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is the problem with this? This statement only copies the content  from container2 to container1. If you need to move the content you need to add another statement to clear container2 e.g. $('#container2').empty();

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Tu7Nc/1/

You must append not your div exactly, but your div's content(inner HTML) with Jquery's `html()` function.

HTML:

```
<div id="1">aaa</div>
<div id="2">bbb</div>​
```

Jquery:

```
$("#1").append($("#2").html());
```

Result:

```
aaabbb
bbb
```

Comment: This is copying, not moving.

Comment: Note that the conversion from DOM to HTML to DOM has consequences, such as dropping references to elements and removing listeners. That may or may not be expected or desirable.

Answer (score 14):

It is best not to use `html()`.

I ran into some issues due to html interpreting the contents as a string instead of a DOM node.

Use contents instead and your other scripts should not break due to broken references.

I needed to nest the contents of a DIV into a child of itself, here is how I did it.

example:

```
<div id="xy">
  <span>contents</span>
</div>

<script>
  contents = $("#xy").contents(); //reference the contents of id xy
  $("#xy").append('<div class="test-class" />'); //create div with class test-class inside id xy 
  $("#xy").find(">.test-class").append(contents); //find direct child of xy with class test-class and move contents to new div
</script>
```

**[EDIT]**

The previous example works but here is a cleaner and more efficient example:

```
<script>
    var content = $("#xy").contents(); //find element
    var wrapper = $('<div style="border: 1px solid #000;"/>'); //create wrapper element
    content.after(wrapper); //insert wrapper after found element
    wrapper.append(content); //move element into wrapper
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, tried using html() and it didn't work for nesting, but this does.  Cheers!

Answer (score 12):

To move contents of a div (id=container2) to another div (id=container1) with jquery.

```
$('#container2').contents().appendTo('#container1');
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also do:

```
var el1 = document.getElementById('container1');
var el2 = document.getElementById('container2');
if (el1 && el2) el1.appendChild(el2);
```

or as one statement, but not nearly as robust:

```
document.getElementById('container1').appendChild(document.getElementById('container2'));
```

#### Edit

On reflection (several years later…) it seems the intention is to move the content of one div to another. So the following does that in plain JS:

```
var el1 = document.getElementById('container1');
var el2 = document.getElementById('container2');
if (el1 && el2) {
  while (el2.firstChild) el1.appendChild(el2.firstChild);
}

// Remove el2 if required
el2.parentNode.removeChild(el2);
```

This has the benefit of retaining any dynamically added listeners on descendants of *el2* that solutions using innerHTML will strip away.

Comment: @Zoltar—well spotted. ;-) It's helpful for those who search on the question but don't want a jQuery answer. Anyway, I see now that the OP wants to copy the content over, not just append the element itself, so I'll fix that.

Comment: I really appreciate the pure javascript solution.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#container1').append($('#container2').html())`

Answer (score 0):

Well, this one could be an alternative if you want to Append:

```
document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML=document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML+document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML
```

if you wanted to rewrite contents:

```
document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML=document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a general approach with a function and jQuery:

```
function MoveContent(destId, srcId) {

    $('#' + destId).append($('#' + srcId).contents().detach());
}
```

Content of a detached source node is appended to a destination node with call:

```
MoveContent('dest','src');
```

The first parameter is an id of a new parent node (destination), the second is an id of an old parent node (source).

Please see an example at: http://jsfiddle.net/dukrjzne/3/